# Rendering/drawing on the desktop wallpaper using Python (In Ubuntu with Gnome)

Tags: python, ubuntu

Is there a way to render/draw on the Ubuntu Gnome desktop in Python 2.6+? I'd like to write a custom app with features like Rainmeter on Windows to display information from servers, feeds, etc.

I've tried the code http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2007/08/24/drawing-on-your-desktop/ but it doesn't work. It just creates a new window and draws on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [gdesklets](http://gdesklets.de/) out. It seems to be a Python-friendly framework for doing exactly what you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this question whilst playing with conky [conky on sourceforge](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) - it can draw to the desktop and can be configured to display information such as weather feeds, mail etc..